# Module/Build.pm can not be located for perl

Tags: perl

I am not a perl expert (see [this page](http://grch37.ensembl.org/info/docs/api/api_installation.html#variation)), but for using a package, I have to run some perl commands. The command shows this error

```
$ perl Build.PL
Can't locate Module/Build.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/mahmood/src/bioperl-1.6.1 /home/mahmood/src/ensembl/modules 
/home/mahmood/src/ensembl-compara/modules /home/mahmood/src/ensembl-variation/modules 
/home/mahmood/src/ensembl-funcgen/modules /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl 
/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at Build.PL line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Build.PL line 20.
```

I see this [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21784614/859227) which offers running `cpan Module::Build` first to fix that error. As I run that command, I see a bunch of questions (text wizard) which asks me a mirror url. Then it interactively asks my permission to install the packages. It seems that default answers to the questions has such effect. I also, didn't find which question is responsible for that. Please see the full output at [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/PShE8uvQ).

Is there any way to automatically install the module, so that I can put that in a script for future things.

UPDATE:

It seems that I have to enter the cpan.org url however in my previous attempt, I used mirror websites. I tried the three commands proposed in the reply, but still get the same error:

```
Please enter the URL of your CPAN mirror  http://www.cpan.org
Configuration does not allow connecting to the internet.
Current set of CPAN URLs:
  http://www.cpan.org
Enter another URL or RETURN to quit: []
New urllist
  http://www.cpan.org


Please remember to call 'o conf commit' to make the config permanent!


cpan shell -- CPAN exploration and modules installation (v1.9402)
Enter 'h' for help.

cpan[1]> o conf build_requires_install_policy yes
    build_requires_install_policy [yes]
Please use 'o conf commit' to make the config permanent!


cpan[2]> o conf prerequisites_policy follow
    prerequisites_policy [follow]
Please use 'o conf commit' to make the config permanent!


cpan[3]> o conf commit
commit: wrote '/home/mahmood/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm'

cpan[4]> quit
No history written (no histfile specified).
Lockfile removed.
mahmood@cluster:Bio-DB-HTS$ perl Build.PL
Can't locate Module/Build.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/mahmood/src/bioperl-1.6.1 /home/mahmood/src/ensembl/modules /home/mahmood/src/ensembl-compara/modules /home/mahmood/src/ensembl-variation/modules /home/mahmood/src/ensembl-funcgen/modules /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at Build.PL line 20.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Build.PL line 20.
```

Comment: Now you have to run `cpan Module::Build` before running `./Build.PL`

Comment: OK. It is now downloading. It also need root permission. I will come back later.

Comment: What is the procedure to delete all temp files if I want to retry from scratch?

Comment: You need root because you're using the system Perl. That's a whole different conversation. I'm glad you're at least up and rolling. It's not advisable to muck with the system Perl; many people use [Perlbrew](http://perlbrew.pl).

Comment: Delete your configuration file you mean? Just `rm /home/mahmood/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to install Module::Build into your system libraries, then it's probably far easier to use the pre-built package that is almost certainly available for your system.

If you're using a RedHat-like Linux distribution, try:

```
$ sudo yum install perl-Module-Build
```

(Try `dnf` instead of `yum` on newer versions of Fedora.)

If you're using a Debian-like Linux distribution, try:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmodule-build-perl
```

Comment: OK. That was good. Thanks. But not all packages are there in repository :( I am struggling with others!

Answer (score 1):

Now that you've got `cpan` configured, you can change the configuration to bypass asking you to install each dependency.

On the command line (note the `o` characters are literal... they are not points):

```
cpan
o conf build_requires_install_policy yes
o conf prerequisites_policy follow
o conf commit
```

To see a description of each item before entering your response manually:

```
cpan

o conf init build_requires_install_policy

When a module declares another one as a 'build_requires' prerequisite
this means that the other module is only needed for building or
testing the module but need not be installed permanently. In this case
you may wish to install that other module nonetheless or just keep it
in the 'build_dir' directory to have it available only temporarily.
Installing saves time on future installations but makes the perl
installation bigger.

You can choose if you want to always install (yes), never install (no)
or be always asked. In the latter case you can set the default answer
for the question to yes (ask/yes) or no (ask/no).

 <build_requires_install_policy>
Policy on installing 'build_requires' modules (yes, no, ask/yes,
ask/no)? [yes] 


o conf init prerequisites_policy

The CPAN module can detect when a module which you are trying to build
depends on prerequisites. If this happens, it can build the
prerequisites for you automatically ('follow'), ask you for
confirmation ('ask'), or just ignore them ('ignore').  Choosing
'follow' also sets PERL_AUTOINSTALL and PERL_EXTUTILS_AUTOINSTALL for
"--defaultdeps" if not already set.

Please set your policy to one of the three values.

 <prerequisites_policy>
Policy on building prerequisites (follow, ask or ignore)? [follow]
```

After you've set them, don't forget to do a:

```
o conf commit
```

...to save your changes.

Now run:

```
cpan Module::Build
```

...and finally, run your build script:

```
./Build.PL
```

Comment: As I saw the interactive package installation was bothering, I pressed ctrl+c. Now, when I run `cpan`, it says `Sorry, we have to rerun the configuration dialog for CPAN.pm due to some missing parameters...`. So it asks again for <cpan_home> and other things. So I can not enter ` o cpan ...`

Comment: @mahmood Just go through the configuration. The defaults are very sane, so on your first pass, just use all the defaults, and go from there.

Comment: I trapped in the same place as before. It asks about mirror url. Please see the updated post. Do you mean I have to finish that interactive package installation once for all?

Comment: Just skip that section (hit `ENTER`). It's asking for *additional* mirrors. You usually don't need any.

Comment: If you mean `Please enter the URL of your CPAN mirror`, I pressed enter which results in bringing up that message again. As you can see in the full output, after asking whether is are ftp/http proxies or not, it asks for mirror url